# Sum of a measure in a Excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm working in a pivot table that contains several measures based only on SUM function. Is there any way to use the SUM function for already created measures. For example, for the measure XDR which is a percentage I want to use SUM of XDR divided by 10 to find out the average XDR over 10 stores.

Thank you,

Comment: A small example dataset with expected result would be useful.

Comment: You may have a look here for calculated values in Pivot tables: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-values-in-a-pivottable-11f41417-da80-435c-a5c6-b0185e59da77 it’s possible to user-define formula